# Rails html.erb mailer view: Resize an image and keep the high resolution

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image with the following specs: 1920x795, resolution:300pixels inside the `application.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to image_tag('logo.png'), root_path, :class => "image_container img " %>
```

and this is the css in order to resize the image:

```
.image_container img
  width: 94px
  height: 40px
  position: relative
```

Everything works perfectly, the image gets resized and also looks sharp too. Now, I'm trying to do the same thing inside a mailer view but I cant get the image to resize according to the css settings. The image appears at it's full size.

Any ideas on how to resize the image inside the html.erb mailer view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you're using an external stylesheet to maintain CSS for mailer views, I would like to tell you that it won't work.

> You need to have inline styles for mailer views. Gmail even drops `<style>` tags. So have inline styling and then check again.

Answer (score -1):

First you don't need to have :

```
:class => "image_container img "
```

just say :

```
:class => "image_container"
```

In the application.html.erb file you need to have

```
<%= styleseet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

and the render of the mailer view

```
<%= render 'mailerviewname' %>
```

And have the following file :

> app>assets>stylessheets>application.scss

Then that will work

Comment: You can't use CSS file with mailer views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Benjamin Barbé... I don't understand the `<%= render 'mailerviewname' %>` what is the purpose of this? I have the mailer along with the html.erb views, I want the image to be inside for example template.html.erb

Comment: try using <style> tag

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé You shouldn't even use <style> tags. Google and other providers even drop those tags. The only correct way to do this is having inline style.You better read this blog https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-css-inlining-in-email